# Reading data from a file and into a struct

Tags: c

I'm trying to read in data from a file and store the data in a struct.  The struct looks like this:

```
struct someData {
    int number;
    char *name;
};
```

The data in the file can be any format.  Right now I'm trying to just read in CSV format.  The data will always be a string followed by an integer.

```
some string data,100
another string,500
```

Here is the part of the code where I'm trying to read the data and place it in the struct.

```
FILE *ifp;
char *mode = "r";
char *name;
int number;

ifp = fopen("myDataFile.txt", mode);

if (ifp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
    exit(1);
}

// read up to 100 characters up to a comma, then a decimal
while(fscanf(ifp, "%100[^,],%d\n", name, &number) != EOF){ 

    // print out the data we got 
    printf("Data from file:  %s  %d", name, number);


    struct someData *newData = (struct someData *) malloc(sizeof(struct someData));
    newData->number = number;
    newData->name = name;
    printf("Name: %s  Number: %d\n\n",newData->name, newData->number);
    }
```

The print statements give me the following

```
Data from file: some string d 100
Name: some string d  Number: 100

Data from file: another stri  Number: 500
Name: another stri  Number 500
```

The second name gets cut off and actually ends up printing a couple of weird characters.  I think something is wrong with my fscanf in the while loop.  I've tried a few other ways to get the data like using %s instead of %100 but nothing is working.

Comment: `char *name;`  name doesn't points to an array. before fscanf in `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the *second* `char *name;` to `char name[101];` (not the one in the `struct`).

And it would be better if you changed:

```
    while(fscanf(ifp, "%100[^,],%d\n", name, &number) != EOF){
```

to

```
    while(fscanf(ifp, " %100[^,],%d", name, &number) == 2){
```

This:

- Adds skipover of initial white space
- Removes trailing `\n`, which can sometime cause problems
- Verifies that two valid arguments have been read.

Also `newData->name = name;` won't work: you'll need something like `newData->name = strdup(name);`.

Also, as a matter of style, I would suggest changing:

```
     struct someData *newData = (struct someData *) malloc(sizeof(struct someData));
```

to:

```
     struct someData *newData = malloc(sizeof *newData);
```

which will avoid some redundancy i.e. "DRY".

And you never save `newData`; I presume you are planning to add it to a linked-list or some other such container.

Also, you'll eventually need to add error-checking, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on strdup() that was my next problem.  And yes it is going into a tree after this.

Comment: @JDD: Just to clarify one point. The trailing `\n` you had in `fscanf` does not mean "eat up a newline". It means "eat up all (zero or more) _white-space_ characters until a non-white-space character or end-of-file is encountered" (the rule within a `%[...]` is different). So what you had was not wrong, but my suggestion is safer in general. But my solution still has the potential problem of `name` having _trailing_ spaces, which may not be what you want, and can cause problems. You'll have to remove these by hand, or use e.g. `Trim`. Also, you may want to use `%100[^,\n]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using not-initialised pointer node. The function fscanf requires for strings some buffer, and you do not provide any.